# How do I see which tables in MySQL are compressed?

Tags: mysql

I just created a new replication server for a MySQL database and when I loaded the mysql_dump I received the error `ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 279: Row size too large (> 8126)`. Seems reasonable, the rows are too large. The problem is that these too large rows are already in the database and I've been told that some of the tables may have compression turned on.

How can I see which tables have compression turned on? Why wasn't the compression transferred with the mysql_dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESCRIBE table_name` and `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name;` don't give any information about compression but if you use

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
```

Then it will display the ROW_FORMAT as well as some other useful things like data length and average row length.